# Flutter : Creating animation controller in stateless widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Is there a way to create animationController inside a stateless widget? Presently I am unable to pass vsync:this inside controller constructor...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can't because `StatelessWidget` doesn't implement `State` which `SingleTickerProvider` `mixin` is defined to work only on classes that implement it
If you are looking for a clean solution see [flutter hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks) they let you use an animation contoller without the boilerplate needed if you use `StatefulWidget`

Comment: you can use any `State`that mixes with `TickerProviderStateMixin`  - for example `Scaffold.of()` method gives you `ScaffoldState` which you can use as a `vsync` parameter

Comment: @pskink but this does not discard my answer right?you can't use the stateless widget directly with the mixin
also in this case if you define animation controllers how will you dispose them?

Comment: This tutorial from flutter.dev says " Dispose of the controller when the State object is discarded to prevent memory leaks."
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/tutorial

Comment: I found a workaround, I passed the Ticker object from parent (which is stateful) to child (which is stateless), so now I am able to use animationController inside stateless widget